# NetBeans and Zend Framework debug

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, netbeans, zend-framework2, xdebug

I need to debug my Zend project with NetBeans but it's not work.

My configuration in php.ini:

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

These also not work:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
{...}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem you are facing while doing it? Have you tested it?

Comment: thanks for responding .. netbeans-xdebug still running without any results !!

Comment: Have your read [netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_configure_XDebug)?

Comment: I think there are two `php.ini` in `wamp` one reside in apache folder and other one is reside in php folder. So have you applied changes on both php.ini???

Comment: thank you @IndrasinhBihola  i resolve my probleme by applied the changes on both php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two PHP Configuration files in **WAMP Server**

The first is used by the command line: `C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpX.X.XX\php.ini`

The second is used by Apache Server: `C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpX.X.XX\phpForApache.ini`

You need to make changes in **the second configuration file** which is used by Apache Server.